# Merging text files and delete file when you are done

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge

I am merging a bunch of text files into "merged.txt". Then I use collections.counter to count the number of all the words in the merged.txt. I am wondering if there is a way to delete the file merged.txt after I have mydict. Or really just a way so that I don't have merged.txt in my directory after the code executes?

```
file_list = [file1, file2, ... file1000]
    with open(directory + '/' + i +'/merged.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for fname in file_list:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)

    words = re.findall(r'\w+', open(directory + '/' + i + '/merged.txt').read().lower())
    mydict = collections.Counter(words)
```

Comment: you could also just count the words without writing the result out to the 'merged.txt' file .. save some io

Comment: What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os                                 
os.remove(file_to_remove)
```

to remove the file.

or:

```
import shutil
shutil.move(file_to_move,destination).
```

to move it.

[os.remove](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) , [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)